# SSI problem with http in centos

Tags: apache-httpd

My httpd.conf is as below.

```
- - -

AddType text/html .shtml .html
Options +Includes
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml .html

DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html index.php index.html.var

- - -
```

And still showing in the debug log Options +Includes wasn't set.

```
[Thu Aug 14 01:14:26 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_include: 
Options +Includes (or IncludesNoExec) wasn't set, INCLUDES filter removed.
```

My apache version is 2.2 & running on Centos 6.

Any advice how to solve this issue.

Comment: Woah, SSI. Talk about a blast from the past. Have you checked to see if there's a `<Directory>` directive somewhere that overrides this setting? Or anything that would render this `Options` directive moot (such as being inside a `<Directory>` itself)?

Comment: did some virtual host config that fix the issue. thanks for the comment Joel.

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix.

Used the virtual hosting to config to fix the issue:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes MultiViews Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

with my current config.